# Can I typdef an enum that is an extension of another typdef enum?

Tags: c, enums, typedef

I would like to typdef an enum that is an extension of another typdef enum.

One typedef enum has 4 elements (because I only have 2 bits in a struct into which to store its value), the other one has the same 4 elements, plus a 5th one (not stored in the struct, only used to mark an invalid value).

Sample code:

```
typedef enum {
    case0,
    case1,
    case2,
    case3,  
} case_t;

typedef enum {
    one_t,         // 0 through 3 <---HOW CAN I DO THIS?
    invalid_case,  // 4 
} case_ext_t

struct {
    case_t   case_       :2; // 2 bits, for up to 4 cases
    unsigned other_stuff:14; // 
} a_word;

case_ext_t my_case = invalid_case;
if (condition) {
    my_case = case2;
}

if (my_case != invalid_case) {
    switch (my_case) {
        case case0: {....} break;
        case case1: {....} break;
        case case2: {....} break;
        case case3: {....} break;
    }
}
```

Can I typedef a case_ext_t that includes all the elements of case_t, plus additional ones?

Alternatively, can I define just the larger typedef enum case_ext_t, yet use only its first 4 elements when storing it 2 bits of a struct?

Comment: You **can** extend the values of an `enum` with another one. Set the first value of the second `enum`, to the last value of the first `enum` +1. Then when you refer to any of those `enum` identifiers, it will be unique. Although why `typedef` an `enum` eludes me. KISS.

Comment: @Waether Vane > why typedef an enum eludes me... I use them extensively; for example, see my code above: I typedef an enum and then use it as the type for an element in a struct (instead of "unsigned")

Answer (score 2):

> Can I typedef a case_ext_t that includes all the elements of case_t, plus additional ones?

No, you can't.  If an identifier is declared as an enumeration constant in a given translation unit, then that must be the only declaration of that identifier in the translation unit (C2011, 6.7/5).  Thus, if two enumerated types are used in the same translation unit, except as incomplete types, then they cannot have any enumeration constants in common.

> Alternatively, can I define just the larger typedef enum case_ext_t, yet use only its first 4 elements when storing it 2 bits of a struct?

No.  A bitfield declaration may not specify more bits than the field's base type actually has (C2011, 6.7.2.1/4).  Moreover, it is implementation-defined whether you can use enumerated types as bit fields' declared types at all, regardless of the number of bits specified; the only types that are guaranteed to be allowed are `_Bool`, `signed int`, and `unsigned int` (C2011, 6.7.2.1/5).

I think your best bet is to declare your bitfield as type `unsigned int`, and to declare only the larger enumerated type:

```
typedef enum {
    case0,
    case1,
    case2,
    case3,  
    invalid_case,  // 4 
} case_t;

struct {
    unsigned case_:2;
    unsigned other_stuff:14;
} a_word;
```

Use appropriate tests for `invalid_case` to protect assignments to `a_word.case_`.

---

Alternatively, do you really need to use bitfields at all?  That seems to be causing a lot of your consternation, and it's not at all clear that the trouble is worth it.  Why not simply use

```
struct {
    case_t case_;
    unsigned other_stuff;
} a_word;
```

?

Comment: > do you really need to use bitfields at all? ... Yes: it's an embedded application, and the word, as defined, bit by bit, is used by other components in the system.

Comment: @DavideAndrea, in that case, be aware that `struct a_word` may not be interchangeable with a plain 16-bit integer.  In particular, the compiler is not required to lay out the two bitfields in 16 contiguous bits, and if it does, then their relative order within those 16 bits is implementation-defined.  Moreover, the overall struct may have trailing padding.

Comment: I do handle that detail (with a "packed" attribute). Still, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend an enumerate with values of another one.

But you could use a little macro trick to do what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define base_enum(prefix) prefix##case0,prefix##case1,prefix##case2,prefix##case3

typedef enum {
    base_enum() 
} case_t;

typedef enum {
    base_enum(ext_),
    invalid_case,  // 4 
} case_ext_t;


int main()
{
   printf("Base %d, ext %d, %d\n",case1,ext_case1,invalid_case);
return 0;
}
```

So you define your base enumerate within the macro, using a prefix.

Then use the macro without prefix when declaring `case_t`, and with another prefix when declaring the "extended" enumerate. You can add other enumerates after the macro.

My example prints: `Base 1, ext 1, 4`